# No connection string could be found in the App.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit

Visual Studio Solution:

(Project 1) I have a ASP .NET Framework API project that uses Entity Framework to access to Database.

(Project 2) Now I created NUnit project that is calling methods of project 1. Some of project1's methods are calling EF methods, so:

- I added nuget package of Entity framework to project 2
- I created an    App.config file in project 2

But after executing test methods I get:

> Test method Test.SchedulerTesting.TestMethod5 threw exception:
> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named
> 'MyEntities1' could be found in the application config
> file.

My app.config (project 2) content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyEntities1" connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**********;initial catalog=******;user id=sa;password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

My Model.Context.cs (project 1) first lines:

```
public partial class MyEntities1: DbContext
{
    public MyEntities1()
        : base("name=MyEntities1")
    {
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app.config file applies when your production application is running. When running tests under a test runner, you need to set up a config for use with your tests. It will usually contain the same stuff as your production config.

In your case, you need a config file named something like `project2.dll.config` in order for the configuration to be made available to your tests. Visual Studio will not automatically rename an `App.config` for you because it doesn't know you want to use NUnit.

Funny thing, the first blog post I ever wrote (2005) talks about this and has many more details: http://charliepoole.org/technical/how-nunit-finds-config-files.html

Comment: Thank you a lot. I used `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath` to check what path was being used by NUnit (`testhost.dll.config`), so I renamed `App.config` to `testhost.dll.config` and finally I could run my tests!!