# NUnit tests fail because : No connection string named 'someEntities' could be found in the application config file, although it exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit

I have a solution with 2 projects.  The primary project is the MVC web application.  The second project in the solution is NUnit tests for the repositories and the controllers in the MVC project.  I have an app.config file in the NUnit project that has the following setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<entityFramework>
<providers>
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SomeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/..." />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have a Web.config for the MVC application which also has the same connection string as follows:

```
<entityFramework>
<providers>
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>

    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

The issue is that whenever I try to run the NUnit test I get the following error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named 'SomeEntities' could be found in the application config file.
    TearDown : System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named 'SomeEntities' could be found in the application config file.
  Stack Trace:
```

The same setup works for the MVC project.  What am I missing? Is it the directory that it is placed in or something obvious that I overlooked?

Comment: Is </connectionStrings> in both files?  Either the config file is not being read, the config file is corrupted, or code is reading a different config file.

Comment: Yes, the <connectionStrings> is in both files.

Comment: You can read that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72257269/no-connection-string-could-be-found-in-the-app-config-file